# Sort a Groovy flattened JsonSluper object after parsing

Tags: java, json, groovy

I have a JSON message that after parsing it w/ the JsonSluper the ordering is messed up. I know the ordering isn't important, but I need to put the message back into ascending order after the message is parsed and flatted into single objects, so I can a build a JsonArray and present the message in the proper asc order.

```
String test = """[
{
"AF": "test1",
"BE": "test2",
"CD": "test3",
"DC": "test4",
"EB": "test5",
"FA": "test5"
},
{
"AF": "test1",
"BE": "test2",
"CD": "test3",
"DC": "test4",
"EB": "test5",
"FA": "test5"
}
]"""
```

The parseText produces this:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(test);

[{CD=test3, BE=test2, AF=test1, FA=test5, EB=test5, DC=test4}, {CD=test3,
 BE=test2, AF=test1, FA=test5, EB=test5, DC=test4}]
```

After parsing the json message, I need to pass the flatten json object into a method at which point needs to be sorted in ascending order by the map keys prior to adding to a JSONArray like below.

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(test);
for( int c = 0; c < json?.size(); c++ )
    doSomething(json[c]);

void doSomething( Object json ){
    def jSort= json.????
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.add(jSort);
}
```

​

Comment: What do you want to sort? the map keys (AF, BE, ...)?

Comment: Yup, that is what I need to do. I modified the question above to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sort entries before adding them. The following uses `collectEntries`, which creates `LinkedHashMap` objects (thus preserving order):

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(test);

def sortedJson = json.collect{map -> map.entrySet().sort{it.key}
                     .collectEntries{[it.key, it.value]}}
```

`sortedJson` has this content, which seems to be sorted as required:

```
 [[AF:test1, BE:test2, CD:test3, DC:test4, EB:test5, FA:test5], 
  [AF:test1, BE:test2, CD:test3, DC:test4, EB:test5, FA:test5]]
```

Comment: Thanks Ernest, that is a great idea, but I get the following error when running the code sort snippet above. I'm using Groovy for this application and it doesn't like the entrySet() method. "No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] " do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: @Wildview I'm almost certain that you either made a slight change, or (more likely) you changed your JSON to produce an object (`{}`) rather than an array of objects (`[{},{}]`).

Comment: Actually just see the above edited message. it shows more of what I'm trying to accomplish that doesn't work correctly w/ your sort method.

Comment: @Wildview My answer was based on your sample input, which contained an JSON array. If you need to sort an individual map, then the code must change, of course.

Comment: Your method is assuming there is always more then 1 json object which it works if 2 or more, but fails if 1. I need it to work for 1 to many objects in the json map. Is that not possible?

Comment: It's not assuming that there will be more than one object, but it is expecting a collection data structure, which may contain one or more items. If you edit your question to mention the possibility of flattened single elements, then I could edit the answer too.

Comment: Thank so much for your help. Your previous answer is good and works for entire parsed object, but if I could get help w/ the flatten objects, that would be great as well. I modified the question to be more clear as to what I'm trying to accomplish. I hope you can help me. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you able to determine whether your JSON contains an array before parsing it?

Comment: The json message will always be in array form [{}], but it could have 1 to many objects. I'm determining if it has an array of objects after the parsing it and sending the flatten json array elments 1 by 1 to another function which processes it and loads it into a JSONArray if successful. My goal was to just sort it before adding to the JSONArray, if that is possible.

Comment: Hi Ernest, was there no work around for sorting the flattened json message?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the scenario. But: if your JSON always comes as an array, then you can use the code above to create sorted maps. If you want to sort maps one at a time, in `doSomething` you can do this: `def jSort = json.entrySet().sort{it.key}.collectEntries{[it.key, it.value]}`, which should convert it to a Linked hash map with sorted keys.